# Fulltext search missing words

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ordinance_number (text)
description (text)
keywords (text)
document_vectors (tsvector)
```

I insert into the column document_vectors by combining the other column data:

```
let ordinanceVecs = `${data.ordinance_number} ${keywords} ${entry} ${description}`;
```

I noticed that some words are not in the column document_vectors.  For example I inserted the following keywords:

```
eric-test ordinance trash bin <p>data</p> ordinance out
```

but in the column I only have the following data inside:

```
'bin':6 'data':7 'eric':2 'eric-test':1 'ordin':4,8 'test':3 'trash':5
```

So when I want to search for the word 'Ordinance' :

```
 select * 
 from ordinances.ordinance  
 where
 (
  document_vectors @@ to_tsquery('ordinance') 
  or
  document_vectors @@ to_tsquery('simple',  'ordinance:*')
 )
```

I get the result back.  Partial search up to 'ordinan' works but 'ordinanc' returns 0 results:

```
 select * 
 from ordinances.ordinance  
 where
 (
   document_vectors @@ to_tsquery('ordinanc') 
   or
   document_vectors @@ to_tsquery('simple',  'ordinanc:*')
 )
```

I'm assuming it because of the way PostgreSQL full-text search and lexemes.  But how can I fix it so that any part of a word is searchable and return a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search for substrings, full text search is not the tool for you.

This will work much better using a trigram index:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON ordinances.ordinance USING gin
   (ordinance_number || ' ' || keywords || ' ' || entry || ' ' || description) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Then you can query:

```
SELECT * FROM ordinances.ordinance
WHERE (ordinance_number || ' ' || keywords || ' ' || entry || ' ' || description)
      LIKE '%ordinanc%';
```

To search for a string that begins at a word boundary, you can use regular expressions:

```
WHERE (ordinance_number || ' ' || keywords || ' ' || entry || ' ' || description)
      ~ '\mordinanc'
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Online it shows to use gin(ordinance_number, keywords, entry, description gin_trgm_ops) . What is the difference?

Comment: You mean `CREATE INDEX ... USING gin (ordinance_number gin_trgm_ops, keywords gin_trgm_ops, entry gin_trgm_ops, description gin_trgm_ops)`. That could be used for a query like `... WHERE ordinance_number LIKE '...' OR entry LIKE '...'`, but it is less efficient.

Comment: Ah I see.  Thanks for the solution you provided